# SQL - Delete table with 372 million rows starting from first row

Tags: sql, sql-server, large-data

I have a table with 372 million rows, I want to delete old rows starting from the first ones without blocking the DB. How can I reach that?

The table have

```
id | memberid | type |      timeStamp          | message |
1     123        10    2014-03-26 13:17:02.000    text
```

UPDATE:

I deleted about 30 GB of Space in DB, but my DISC is ON  6gb space yet..
Any suggestion to get that free space?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You want to delete all rows or there is some condition?

Comment: If you're going to delete lots of rows, but not all, do it in chunks.

Comment: You can't. All data manipulation queries will lock the table with at least a schema lock to maintain consistency during the operation. You can delete records in small batches based on a reliable index to decrease the duration of a lock. What did you try so far?

Comment: No, I want to delete from first row till arrive to this year, but a simple select crash DB.. @Utsav

Comment: Why cant you redirect new request to another table ( copy structure of the original with next ID index ) and meanwhile delete the ones on the live table. After that, merge the, together.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select 1;
while(@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
begin
   WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';
   delete top(10) from tab  where <your-condition>;

end
```

delete in chunks using above sql

Comment: Sleep. Add some sleep time.

Comment: added 10 seconds of sleep time @Pred

Comment: What this query exactly does?Starting from the first row delete from 10 to 10 with a delay of 10 seconds? @AksheyBhat

Comment: it will delete rows in small chunks instead of delete all rows at once. It will lock the table for various small periods instead of locking the table for one long period. after deleting 10 rows it will sleep for 10 seconds and then continue until all rows are deleted

Comment: I think you need to switch the delete and watifor.  Waitfor will update @@ROWCOUNT to 0.  Test case: `SELECT 1; WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10.000'; SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;` returns 0.

Comment: @destination-data modified my answer. thanks for your observation

Comment: Any idea of how much number of rows can I delete in every chunk to not crash DB?

Comment: you can try upto 100 rows

Comment: There is no magic number. The sleep time and record count for a batch highly depends on the HW and on the load of the server. You may be able to run 10k batches without any problem at night, when a 1k batch kills the db during office hours. Test it by incrementing the batch size slowly, and/or decrementing the sleep time. The goal is to process as many records as possible in a batch while allowing other queries to run during sleeps.
Either way you'll need a maintenance window later to optimize the table (fix fragmentation) if you choose this method.

Comment: If I use this while, my table size increase when deleting rows. Whats wrong here?

Comment: How are you calculating table size?

Comment: @AksheyBhat I deleted to many rows with your script, How can I see the free space on disk?

Comment: exec <database-name>..sp_spaceused '<table-name>'. use this query

Answer (score 4):

You may want to consider another approach:

1. Create a table based on the existing one
2. Adjust the identity column in the empty table to start from the latest value from the old table (if there is any)
3. Swap the two tables using `sp_rename`
4. Copy the records in batches into the new table from the old table
5. You can do whatever you want with the old table.

**BACKUP your database before you start deleting records / play with tables.**

Comment: I have a problem, Im running now with 6 gb free space in Disc, its imposible to create a copy of this table.

Comment: Not with data. The structure is enough. You want an empty table to continue collecting data.

Answer (score 0):

the best performance is to query data by id, then:

```
delete from TABLENAME where id>XXXXX
```

is the lowest impact you can execute.

You can also divide the operation in suboperations limiting the number of deleted rows for each operation adding ROWCONT declatarion,

example if you want to delete only 5.000.000 of rows per call you can do this:

```
SET ROWCOUNT=5000000;
delete from TABLENAME where id>XXXXX;
```

here you can find a reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms188774%28v=sql.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

> The answer to the best way to delete rows from an Oracle table is: It
>   depends!  In a perfect world where you can take the table offline for
>   maintenance, a complete reorganization is always best because it does
>   the delete and places the table back into a pristine state.  We will
>   address the tools for doing large scale deletes and the appropriate
>   methods for each environment.

Factors and tools for massive deletes

The choice of the delete methods depends on many factors:

1. Is the target table partitioned?  Partitioning greatly improves delete performance.  For example, it is common to have a large time-based table partition and deleting elderly rows from these table can be as simple as dropping the desired partition.  See these notes on managing partitioned tables.
2. Can you reorganize the table after the delete to remove fragmentation?
3. What percentage of the table will be deleted?  In cases where you are deleting more than 30-50% of the rows in a very large table it is faster to use CTAS to delete from a table than to do a vanilla delete and a reorganization of the table blocks and a rebuild of the constraints and indexes.
4. Do you want to release the space consumed by the deleted rows?  If you know that the empty space will be re-used by subsequent DML then you will want to leave the empty space within the table.  Conversely, if you want to released the space back onto the tablespace then you will need to reorganize the table.

There are many tools that you can use to delete from large tables:

1. dbms_metadata.get_ddl:  This procedure wil punch-off the definitions of all table indexes and constraints.
2. dbms_redefinition:  This procedure will reorganize a table while it remains available for updating.
3. Create Table as Select:  You can use CTAS to copy a table while removing rows in bulk.
4. Rename table:  If you copy a table when deleting rows you can rename it back to its original name.
5. COMMIT:  In cases where a delete might run for many hours, even the largest UNDO log will not be able to hold the rollback information and it becomes necessary to do the delete in a PL/SQL loop, issuing a COMMIT every zillion-rows to free-up the undo logs.  This approach will be re-startable automatically because the delete will pick-up where it left off as on your last commit checkpoint.

More information visit [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_fastest_delete_from_large_table.htm)

Comment: this isn't actually about oracle